# How to update a get it instance in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, instance

I am using the getIt package to create instances in my application.

```
instance.registerLazySingleton<DioFactory>(() => DioFactory(instance()));

  // app  service client
  final dio = await instance<DioFactory>().getDio();
  instance.registerLazySingleton<AppServiceClient>(() => AppServiceClient(dio));
```

Above code is for initialising the instances.
The getDio() function:

```
Future<Dio> getDio() async {
    Dio dio = Dio();
    int _timeOut = 60 * 1000; // 1 min
    String language = await _appPreferences.getAppLanguage();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      CONTENT_TYPE: APPLICATION_JSON,
      ACCEPT: APPLICATION_JSON,
      AUTHORIZATION: Constants.token,
      DEFAULT_LANGUAGE: language
    };

    dio.options = BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: Constants.baseUrl,
        connectTimeout: _timeOut,
        receiveTimeout: _timeOut,
        headers: headers);

    if (kReleaseMode) {
    } else {
      dio.interceptors.add(PrettyDioLogger(
          requestHeader: true, requestBody: true, responseHeader: true));
    }

    return dio;
  }
```

When I build my application for the first time the Constants.token has a blank value.
But in the middle of the application I wish to add a value into it. I am able to change that value but when I see the logs from dio logger it still displays the empty string in the "Authorisation" field.

How do I update my instance so that I can change my token value for my API requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to register your dio with registerFactory to getit. In your case you are registering as singleton, that's why it is giving you same instance

Comment: Okay, then using which command should I update it? Because I was using resetLazySingleton() first

Comment: replace registerSingleton with registerFactory

Comment: I did that, but it is not changing the authorisation value. do I have to reset my instance

Comment: how you are accessing your dio, by the logic it should be accessed, when it is needed. Does it work like that?

Comment: I am using it inside AppServiceClient class. It has a dio instance in its constructor.

Comment: It worked. I just had to provide allowReassignment to true

Answer (score 3):

First you should create an interceptor that call TokenInterceptor with override onRequest method. Inside onRequest method you can modify your headers like below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6PFR.png

And final step you only add to your dio interceptor like that:

```
dio.interceptors.add(TokenInterceptor());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final getIt = GetIt.instance;
void setupSingleton(){
getIt.allowReassignment=true;
}
//this should call first and then it will work
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple override method for my needs in the `extension` on GetIt.

```
  @experimental
  override<T extends Object>(dynamic other) {
    try {
      unregister<T>();
    } catch (e) {
      print('[DI]: $e');
    }
    switch (other) {
      case T Function() _:
        registerFactory<T>(other);
      case T _:
        registerLazySingleton<T>(() => other);
      default:
        assert(false, '[DIExtension] Invalid override type');
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```dart
// override instance
GetIt.I.override<CoolDependency>(evenCoolerDependencyInstance);

// override factory
GetIt.I.override<CoolDependency>(()=> evenCoolerDependencyInstance);
```

Not sure why this does not exist in the official GetIt api.
I read this [discussion](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/get_it/issues/42) and it seemed to me like this is not "the GetIt way".
But I suppose that it is because of a vast variety of options to register a dependency:

[image]